# passing function as an argument if you do not know the name of the function yet

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to write a function which accept another function as argument, but I do not know what the function exactly because the user will have two functions to choice from them.  Both of the functions will accept the same arguments
my idea was to get the name of the function the user wants to call which will be stored in projectScoreByXXX then call it but its keep it telling me that function is not defined

```
 Tournament.prototype.projectedLeaderboard= function(projectScoreByXXX){

    for(var i =0; i<jsonObj.tournament.players.length; i++){


        jsonObj.tournament.players[i].score = projectScoreByXXX(jsonObj.tournament.players[i].lastname, jsonObj.tournament.players[i].firstinitial);

    }
    leaderboard();

}
```

}

thank you

when the user wants to call the function he will use
t.projectedLeaderboard(projectScoreByHole);
or t.projectedLeaderboard(projectScoreByIndividual);

projectScoreByIndividual and projectScoreByHole are two functions that I have in my class
projectScoreByXXX is not a function name and  i put it there as the argument name because I do not know which one the user will use By individual or hole 
is there a way to do this?

Comment: I don't understand the problem. Why can't you just do `projectScoreByXXX(jsonObj..., jsonObj...)`. You shouldn't need `bind` or `this`.

Comment: What do you expect *this* to be and why do you think it has a *projectScoreByXXX* property?

Answer (score 3):

You should call the function directly, here's an example to illustrate:

```js
function caller(func, params) { // in your case: projectedLeaderboard, and you're not
                                // using params since like you said
                                // they would have the same arguments
  func(params); // in your case: projectScoreByXXX(jsonObj...., jsonObj...)
}
function f(n) {
  console.log(n**2);
}
function g(n) {
  console.log(Math.sqrt(n));
}
caller(f, 4);
caller(g, 4);
```